# Azure - How can I get application information

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get the name and owner information of an Azure AD application.
The credentials I can use consist of: tenant id, subscription id, client id and client secret.

I found that Microsoft Graph API (I use azure-graphrbac python package) has an `applications.get()` function,
but that throws `GraphErrorException: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`.

According to the documentation it needs this permission - `Application.Read.All`, does that have an action equivalent?
(we use a JSON file to create a custom role with all the other necessary permissions as actions, and give that role to the application)

I tried with these actions:

`Microsoft.Directory/applications/allProperties/read`

`Microsoft.Directory/applications/owners/read`

but the result stays the same, what other actions does it need permission for,
or, alternatively, is there another package I can use to get application info, using the above permissions and other action permissions.

Comment: It seems the permission can only be given via the API Permissions in the app. But this - [Microsoft Graph using MSAL with Python](https://blog.darrenjrobinson.com/microsoft-graph-using-msal-with-python/), helped me with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure one of the following **`Delegated`** and **`application`**  permissions :`Application.Read.All` or Application.ReadWrite.All,`Directory.Read.All` orDirectory.ReadWrite.All or`Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` and `User.Read`  is granted consent to your account having that application.

[image]

- Then you will be able to get the application information .

[image]

As you are using  `microsoft graph`, please make sure the  resource has to be: **`https://graph.microsoft.com`**